How to add multiple LOOKUPVALUE columns in the table with filter on the another table efficiently (in Python)?
I need advices, because I don't have much experience with Python.
I'm thinking a better way (for performance, if it exists) to add multiple LOOKUPVALUE columns in the same table in Python. So, I have the following function to reuse multiple times (8 times) to add LOOKUPVALUE into the table with filtering.
def get_column_value_in_question_by_pk(df, df1, filter, result_column_name, alt_value):

    """Filter column Question by parameter "filter" and rename the lookupvalue column to result_column"""
    df1 = df1.filter(F.col("column_filter") == filter).withColumnRenamed(
        "lookupvalue_column", result_column_name
    )

    df = df.join(df1, df1["pk"] == df["pk"], "left").select(df["*"], df1[result_column_name])

    df = df.withColumn(
        result_column_name,
        F.when(F.col(result_column_name).isNull(), alt_value).otherwise(F.col(result_column_name)),
    )
    return df

It's fine to use it now, but when I reuse it 8 times to create 1 table (because I need those extra columns), then I don't think it's efficient.
Is there better way to do it?
 **Input data:**

    | pk       | column_filter  | lookupvalue_column |
    | -------- | -------------- | --------------     |
    | 123acb   | Location       | City1              |
    | 456bca   | Location       | City2              |
    | 123acb   | Question1      | Unhappy            |
    | 456bca   | Question1      | Disappointed       |
    | 123acb   | Question2      | Happy              |
    | 456bca   | Question2      | Very happy         |

**Expected output:**

    | pk       | Name          | result_column1(filter on Question1)    | result_column2(filter on Question2)     | result_column_name3(on Location)|
    | -------- | ------------- | ---------------------------            | -----------------------                 | --------------------------|
    | 123acb   | Name1         | Unhappy                                | Happy                                   | City1                     |
    | 456bca   | Name2         | Disappointed                           | Very happy                              | City2                     |

                

I call the function like this to add new column into the df dataframe:
get_column_value_in_question_by_pk(df, df1, "Location", "result_column_name3", "None")


please add sample input data and expected data

Please bautify your input and expected data that it is visible for everybody in a better way. Use the show stmt in pandas or sth. similar. Also where do you get the name of the expected data? Do you have an indicator to differ between questions and personal customer data?

Also indent your code correctly. The function right now cannot be a correct python function

@SamuelDemir I updated my question. This function is what i'm currently using in Databricks, it's Pyspark (something familiar with Python). I'm looking for something better in Python, but if there is a better logical way to do it more efficient, then it would be nice

I Provided an answer :) Hope this helps you

You can simply achieve this by pivotting the DataFrame. In case if there is the same question per pk, the first occurance of lookupvalue_column per pk is used.
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data1 = [
    ("123acb", "Location", "City1",),
    ("456bca", "Location", "City2"),
    ("123acb", "Question1", "Unhappy"),
    ("456bca", "Question1", "Disappointed"),
    ("123acb", "Question2", "Happy"),
    ("456bca", "Question2", "Very Happy"),
    ("456bca", "Question3", None),
]

columns1 = ["pk", "column_filter", "lookupvalue_column"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, columns1)

data2 = [
    ("123acb", "Name1"),
    ("456bca", "Name2"),
]

columns2 = ["pk", "Name"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, columns2)

df_pivot = (
    df1.withColumn("pivot_col", f.concat(f.lit("result_"), f.col("column_filter")))
    .groupBy("pk")
    .pivot("pivot_col")
    .agg(f.first(f.col("lookupvalue_column")))
)

df_result = (
    df2
    .join(df_pivot, ["pk"], "left")
    .fillna("default_val", subset=["result_Question3"])
)


Result df_pivot:
+------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|    pk|result_Location|result_Question1|result_Question2|result_Question3|
+------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|123acb|          City1|         Unhappy|           Happy|            NULL|
|456bca|          City2|    Disappointed|      Very Happy|            NULL|
+------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+

Result df_result:
+------+-----+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|    pk| Name|result_Location|result_Question1|result_Question2|result_Question3|
+------+-----+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|123acb|Name1|          City1|         Unhappy|           Happy|     default_val|
|456bca|Name2|          City2|    Disappointed|      Very Happy|     default_val|
+------+-----+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+

